# Cannot Get a Text Inside a <td> With jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, datatables, jeditable

I have a `<td>` element like this one:

`<td class="right editable qty">100</td>`

I want to get the value inside that (`100`) but got some problem.

Here is my script:

```
$('#example tbody tr td.qty').change(function () {
    var sQty = $(this);

    console.log(sQty); // print [<td class="right editable qty">100</td>]
    console.log($.text(sQty)); // print nothing
    console.log(sQty.val()); // print nothing
    console.log(sQty.text()); // print nothing
    console.log(sQty.html()); // print <form><input style="width: 100%; height: 100%; " autocomplete="off" name="value"></form>
});
```

Is there something missing with my script?

*I'm working with: [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) and [jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)*

Comment: TD elements do not trigger the _change_ event. You can use _click_.

Comment: You can use click method. http://jsfiddle.net/RJCxt/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* Apply the jEditable handlers to the table */
oTable.$('td.editable').editable(
    function(value, settings) {
        if($(this).hasClass('qty')) // The editable class not only on one column.
            console.log(value);
        return(value);
    },
    {   
        "height": "100%",
        "width": "100%"
    }
);
```

When I'm trying to run the `jEditable` handlers and `change` events (on question above), I found that the `change` events will be trigger first and after that the `jEditable` handlers. What the `jEditable` handlers will do is return the `value` and set into the cell that has been edit.

For the default the table cell will be look like this:

`<td class="right editable qty">1</td>`

When I click the cell it will generate this form:

```
<td class="rigth editable qty">
    <form>
        <input style="width: 100%; height: 100%; " autocomplete="off" name="value">
    </form>
</td>
```

As we see the value of the cell is disappear (This form I got when trying to inspect the element with firebug). And when I try to change the value of the `input` element inside the `form` the firebug didn't show anything change at all (the value is hidden somewhere). So when I press the `Enter` button I realize that `change` event will be trigger first and for that moment the `<td>` elements is still empty, so that's why when we try to print the value is still empty.

So instead of using the `change` events to get the value, I'm using the `jEditable` handlers before it returns the value into the cell (the handler will be trigger if we press the `Enter` button).

Answer (score 5):

You can get the value with `$(selector).text();`

Change

```
console.log($.text(sQty));
```

To

```
console.log(sQty.text());
```

Answer (score 2):

I write this in case someone finds this question

When trying to select various `<td>`, in order to get (or set) each value from the multiple `<td>` tags, like this:

```
<td class='myClass'>1</td>
<td class='myClass'>2</td>
<td class='myClass'>3</td>
```

If you use `.text()`, `.val()` or `.html()`, as follows:

```
//Example
var tdContainer;
for (int k = 0; k < $("td.myClass").length; k++){
     var tdContainer = $("td.myClass")[k].text() + ", "; //Throws "Uncaught TypeError"
}
```

Javascript throws an error, returning "[used method] is not a function".

In this case, the **solution** is to use `.textContent`:

```
//Example
var tdContainer;
for (int k = 0; k < $("td.myClass").length; k++){
     tdContainer += $("td.myClass")[k].textContext + ", ";
}
```

Hope this helps some of you.

Answer (score 1):

tips:  from [.change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) documentation

> The **change** event is sent to an element when its value changes. This
>   event is limited to  elements,  boxes and 
>   elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons.

so get the text with  [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
console.log($('#example td.qty').text());
```

Comment: Do we really need $('#example tbody tr td.qty')? Can it be done with $('.qty')?

Comment: @diEcho: Because there are more than 1 `<td>` with same `class` attribute it will print the other `<td>` value except the changed `<td>`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `td` doesnt have a `change` property use `click` instead

```
$('#example tbody tr td.qty').click(function () {
    var sQty = $(this);

    console.log(sQty.html()); // print [<td class="right editable qty">100</td>]
    console.log(sQty.text()); // print 100
    console.log(sQty.val()); // nothing will print,val() is for input type elements
});
```

Answer (score 0):

hiii friend,

You can simply get the value from table column of table row by selecting that column with class name(.righteditableqty) and then select text with .text() function.

or use that script:

***`$(".righteditableqty").Text()`***